# How to dual boot my laptop with windows 7 having preloaded ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Basically I want to install Windows 7 on a preloaded Ubuntu 12.04 laptop. How can I dual boot it?

I want to keep my Ubuntu safe and also want to roll back the changes after some months. I have tried booting Win7 via flash drive but it didn't work. How do I do this? Please help!

Comment: Try **winusb** software on ubuntu to make a bootable windows usb.

Answer (score 0):

See [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) page for how to install windows after Ubuntu.Please backup your important datas before you proceed.